# Paypal IPN $custom Variable not working with PHP

Tags: php, paypal

I have a paypal listener with mailing set up and working just fine, but I am trying to pass a "custom" variable to paypal to return in my IPN to update my database.  The listener is working with the IPN Simulator but I've narrowed it down to the registration page not sending the "custom" information.  I'm not fluent with php by any means, below is the code I am using with my paypal button:

```
<?php
          if(!empty($_POST['name']))
          {
          $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
          $phone = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phone']);
          $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
          $address = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['address']);
          $date = mysql_real_escape_string(date("Y.m.d"));
          $active = mysql_real_escape_string('Active - Not Paid');
          $supportrec = isset($_POST['supportboatsyes']);
          $support10hpban = isset($_POST['support10hpbanyes']);
          $supporttotalban = isset($_POST['supporttotalbanyes']);
          $emaillist = isset($_POST['addtoemailyes']);
          $volunteer = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['volunteer']);              

          $checkusername = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM recreationUsers WHERE Name = '".$name."'");

          if(mysql_num_rows($checkusername) == 1)
          {
          echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
          echo "<p>Sorry, you have already registered. <br /> Please contact the site administrator regarding any issues.</p>";
          }
          else
          {
          $registerquery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO recreationUsers (Name, Phone, Email, Address, Date_added, Status, Support_all_recreation, Support_10hp_ban, Support_no_boats, Email_list, Volunteer) VALUES('".$name."', '".$phone."', '".$email."', '".$address."', '".$date."', '".$active."', '".$supportrec."', '".$support10hpban."', '".$supporttotalban."', '".$emaillist."', '".$volunteer."')");
          if($registerquery)
          {
          $custom = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);

          echo "<h1>Success, please choose your account type below:</h1>";
          echo '<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
                   <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick" />
                   <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="6F6YP6CVBRW92" />
                   <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="$custom" />
                   <table>
                       <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Choose a subscription:" />Choose a subscription:</td></tr>
                       <tr>
                           <td>
                               <select name="os0">
                                   <option value="Individual">Individual: $20.00 CAD - Annual</option>
                                   <option value="Family">Family: $50.00 CAD - Annual</option>
                               </select>
                           </td>
                       </tr>
                   </table>
                   <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="CAD" />                       
                   <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" />
                   <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1" />
                </form>';

          echo "<p>If you don't have a Paypal account Please Click on the next page \"Pay using your credit or debit card.\"</p>";
          }
          else
          {
          echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
          echo "<p>Sorry, your registration failed. Please go back and try again.</p>";
          }
          }
          }
          else
          {
          ?>
```

I've also tried:

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($custom); ?>"
```

and:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $custom); ?>"
```

Can anyone direct me to the correct usage of this please?

Comment: why are you using sql escaping on an html form value? backslashes have absolutely no meaning in html, and are a regular character like any other.

Comment: I was reading a forum and it had worked for someone, Sorry I am completely lost here I don't know where to go with this.

Comment: you already set a variable `$name` why again `$custom` you can use `$name`

Comment: So this should work?      `<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="$custom" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will make the form output with the custom parameter filled in correctly (assuming $custom is getting populated the way you expect it to.)

```
echo '<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
               <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick" />
               <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="AngellEYE_SP_GeneralConsult" />
               <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="6F6YP6CVBRW92" />
               <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="'. $custom . '" />
               <table>
                   <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Choose a subscription:" />Choose a subscription:</td></tr>
                   <tr>
                       <td>
                           <select name="os0">
                               <option value="Individual">Individual: $20.00 CAD - Annual</option>
                               <option value="Family">Family: $50.00 CAD - Annual</option>
                           </select>
                       </td>
                   </tr>
               </table>
               <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="CAD" />                       
               <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" />
               <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1" />
            </form>';
```

To explain further, you're using a single quote to open up your echo statement.  As such, simply using $custom inside that won't actually output the value of $custom, so you need to use the ' . $custom . ' method instead.

If you were using a double quote to open up the echo line, then using $custom directly would work, but then you would also have to escape all of the double quotes inside the form html because they would be closing that echo line if they weren't escaped.

I read somewhere a while ago that it's best to use the single quote as much as possible because if you use double quotes then PHP will look for $phpvars within that content which chews up some processing power on the server.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the alleged efficiency increase of single quotes - it will be so marginal that it's not worth bothering with. Use whatever is the more readable. On that topic, trapping large blocks of HTML inside `echo` statements isn't ideal, since one loses the syntax analysis, tag matching and code colouration of an IDE. It's better to render HTML in PHP's HTML mode, and break into PHP temporarily for the dynamic bits. Or, of course, use a templating engine.

Comment: Thank you!! Works Perfectly now! I need to dive into a little research on php syntax it looks like!